# Modify retrieved data from a database without updating

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net

Is there any way that we can modify the retrieved data from a database without changing the original data? Like `add_filter()` function in PHP.

E.g:  we have a cell in the database called `Gender`, it has two values: `0` (male), and `1` (female). When I show the data I want to replace the `0` with the word "Male" without changing the original 0 in the database! Is it possible?

Comment: in what you are taking the data from database, data-set, list and how ??

Comment: Dataset. in vb.net with SQL commands

Answer (score 1):

Use `CASE` expression in select list, something like:

```
select case gender when 0 then 'Male'
                   when 1 then 'Female'
       end
from ...
```